# dataGridView is empty

Tags: c#, database, datagridview

I'm trying to fill `DataGridView` from database with table data. Here is how:

```
adpt = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
adpt.Fill(dt);

BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = dt;

dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
adpt.Update(dt);
```

But all I see is empty `DataGridView`. Can some show me where I'm wrong or what I'm missing?

Comment: Try to check query

Comment: @RaviMehta query is ok. DataReader works fine.

Comment: Rather than "adpt.Update(dt);" after "dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;", insert "adpt.Fill(dt);" just before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic Function to fill the data gridview is below ,

```
void FillData()
            {
                // 1
                // Open connection
                using (SqlCeConnection c = new SqlCeConnection(
                    Properties.Settings.Default.DataConnectionString))
                {
                    c.Open();
                    // 2
                    // Create new DataAdapter
                    using (SqlCeDataAdapter a = new SqlCeDataAdapter(
                        "SELECT * FROM Animals", c))
                    {
                        // 3
                        // Use DataAdapter to fill DataTable
                        DataTable t = new DataTable();
                        a.Fill(t);
                        // 4
                        // Render data onto the screen
                        dataGridView1.DataSource = t;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Works when pass `DataTable` to `DataGridView`, thank you.